# How to find the relative address of a `FILE*`

Tags: c++, c, file, ros

To find out why I am doing the things described below, you can read [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/195794/can-not-write-an-instance-of-rosbagmessageinstance-to-a-rosbagstream/) question. In short: for some reason the library code request a function that is not defined by the according class, my solution: extend the class by my custom one, write the requested function and use my class.

I have a function `void* advance(uint64_t nbytes)` that would be called somewhere by some library code as `memcpy(object.advance(nbytes), source, nbytes)`. From inside `advance()` I have access to a `FILE*` where the results should be stored, so from what I understand I have to return a pointer which will have an address relative to the whole memory, but be inside `FILE*` so that the library code can write appropriately.

What I've tried so far:

```
void* advance(uint64_t nbytes){
    return this->getFilePointer()->_IO_buf_base;
}

void* advance(uint64_t nbytes){
    return this->getFilePointer()->_IO_write_base;
}
```

Since I am not familiar with how memory allocation for files works in general, I assumed that technically it should be allocated as well, hence I did this:

```
void* advance(uint64_t nbytes){
    char *ptr = new char [nbytes];
    fwrite(ptr,1,nbytes,this->getFilePointer());
    return this->getFilePointer()->_IO_write_base;
}
```

What I realised in my last example that for some reason `this->getFilePointer()->_IO_write_ptr - this->getFilePointer()->_IO_write_base == 125` while `nbytes == 9830525`, hence obviously something is wrong again...

All of the above examples trigger a segfault.

Is my logic correct, i.e. does it make sense to do what I am doing? If yes, how can I achieve the right result?

p.s. I tried to make the question as short as possible, if any additional information is needed I will provide it.

EDITS:

This is the code that calls `advance()`

```
void Bag::readMessageDataIntoStream(IndexEntry const& index_entry, Stream& stream) const {
    ros::Header header;
    uint32_t data_size;
    uint32_t bytes_read;
    switch (version_)
    {
    case 200:
    {
        decompressChunk(index_entry.chunk_pos);
        readMessageDataHeaderFromBuffer(*current_buffer_, index_entry.offset, header, data_size, bytes_read);
        if (data_size > 0)
            memcpy(stream.advance(data_size), current_buffer_->getData() + index_entry.offset + bytes_read, data_size);
        break;
    }
    case 102:
    {
        readMessageDataRecord102(index_entry.chunk_pos, header);
        data_size = record_buffer_.getSize();
        if (data_size > 0)
            memcpy(stream.advance(data_size), record_buffer_.getData(), data_size);
        break;
    }
    default:
        throw BagFormatException((boost::format("Unhandled version: %1%") % version_).str());
    }
}
```

Where `Stream` would be my object which would inherit from [this](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rosbag/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1Stream.html#abdb470bf175372f745bc537fac036141) one

I tried this as well:

```
char *ptr;
void* advance(uint64_t nbytes){
        ptr = new char [nbytes];
        return ptr;
}
```

It obviously worked, but it is not what I try to achieve as in this case I will have to parse the data on my own, which I try to avoid.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. A `FILE *` is a pointer to a `FILE` structure, which is an opaque control block for an open file. You don't want to be passing anybody any addresses inside that structure for any reason whatsover.

Comment: He's talking about the glibc-specific implementation in `libio.h`. It would help if he mentioned that, though.

Comment: Strong assertions in the first sentence. I know I can read that C++ related question, if I wanted to. I'm sure everyone else here does as well.

Comment: It would seem your code would expect to have `advance(size_t n)` return a pointer valid for at least `n` bytes to be writeable, and such that exactly `n` bytes is written..

Comment: Also, poking at the implementation, it seems there's some double buffering going on (!) during which the stream class buffers data in and out of the `FILE*` object (which happens to make no sense, since the `FILE*` is buffered anyway..)

Comment: @mnunberg, yes, but If I would return a pointer allocated by me, I would have to parse the chunk of data on my own, which I try to avoid by the use of the library...

Comment: @EJP could you please check the edit, maybe I misinterpreted what the author of the library tried to do with `memcpy()`

Comment: It looks like you need to poke around and make use of the methods implemented here maybe? http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rosbag/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1ChunkedFile.html. To be clearer, it seems that the `advance()` methods peek into the `ChunkedFile`, rather than the `FILE*` object itself. Note, that there's a `->file_` member, and a `->file_->file_` member :/

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "parse data on my own" ? What I understand is that `advance` is the way your library gives you control over the data stream. You can't access internal `FILE` buffer this way, it is only a cache so data will be overwritten over time. You have to manage the memory used by data read/write from/to a file by your own. You can gain control of the cache using `setvbuf` if really needed.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès what happens is that I a call a method `write(Stream)` on an object (which I have no other way to read content from), what happens is that the content is written as a binary chunk of data, so it I write that to my pointer I will have to parse that data on my own, if I write it to the `FILE*` instance I can use the methods that are already defined to do that.

Comment: The fact that your data are written as raw bytes chunks is not a problem by itself. If your source of data is a structured data of your program you are able to read it as the same structure. If you have an `int` (or whatever), write it with `fwrite` to a file, then you are able to read it with `fread`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is not correct as it breaks causality.

First two attempts just attempt at overwriting some FILE's internal data, and thats it. They don't and won't trigger write. Next one writes data before it's copied and then attempts overwriting some unrelated FILE's internal data (which will segfault/GPF of course).

The key problem is that your function is called first and only then data is copied (memcpy). memcpy won't trigger file write by itself.

You can attempt the following instead:

First call of `advance()` just allocates a buffer. Each following call first tries to write the buffer (filled immediately after previous `advance()` call) to file and then allocates data for next buffer. Finally destructor of your object (or some method called after whole copy action if you can do that) writes the data from the buffer allocated in last call, then (optionally) closes the file. I.e. something like the following:

```
class AutoWrite {
 public:
  AutoWrite(FILE* file): file_(file), buffer_(nullptr), size_(0) {}

  ~AutoWrite() {
    flush_last();
    fclose(file_);
  }

  void* advance(uint64_t nbytes) {
    flush_last();
    buffer_ = new char[nbytes];
    size_ = nbytes;
    return buffer;
  }

  void flush_last() {
    if (size_ > 0) {
      fwrite(static_cast<void*>(buffer_), 1, size_, file);
      size_ = 0;
      delete[] buffer_;
    }
  }

 private:
  FILE* file_;
  char* buffer_;
  uint64_t size_;
};
```

The thing has one "feature": data is not saved immediately, instead it's written to disk only directly before the next buffer is to be allocated (or during destruction of object).

PS. Don't mess with FILE internals. It's a bad idea. Not only it's not portable, it might break with any random compiler or standard library update. And it does not solve your problem.